# How to use getBounds() to get pick up map ends with react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

How to get the 4 coordinates that represent the 4 ends visible on the map using `react-leaflet`.

I would like to use the `contains()` function to return true or false for a coordinate that is passed, if it is true it means that it is within the limits established in `getBounds()`, if it is false it is outside.

Just wiht `leaflet` in pure JavaScript I know how to use this function. But I'm developing a React Web Application, and I'm using `react-leaflet` library and need use this function.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-matsumoto-rjffmr?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const center = [51.505, -0.09];

  const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const contains = map.getBounds().contains(center);
      console.log("contains:: ", contains);
    }
  }, [center, map]);

  return (
    <Map
      ref={setMap}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
      center={center}
      zoom={13}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
    </Map>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The documentation is a bit obscure but you should be able to run `LatLngBounds.contains` method with `<Map>.getBounds` by doing `L.latLngBounds( <Map>.getBounds() ).contains(center)`. Here's a specific example on react-leaflet `getBounds` https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-react-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the map.  Then you can access the ref's `.leafletElement` property, which is the map instance:

```js
const App = ({ center }) => {
  const mapRef = useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef) {
      const contains = mapRef.leafletElement.getBounds().contains(center);
    }
  }, [center]);

  return (
    <Map 
      ref={mapRef}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      <TileLayer {...props} />
    </Map>
  );
};
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-tdd-3edr10?file=/src/App.js)

---

### Modern answer for react-leaflet v4

You need a reference to the map, so that you can call things like `L.map.getBounds()`.  react-leaflet no longer uses the `.leafletElement` property since react-leaflet v3.  Here's a v4 answer:

```js
const App = ({ center }) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const contains = map.getBounds().contains(center);
    }
  }, [center]);

  return (
    <Map 
      ref={setMap}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      <TileLayer {...props} />
    </Map>
  );
};
```

The docs have some examples of how to grab the underlying L.map instance as a ref and use it, here: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state/.

Comment: Hii Seth, thank you your help, I updated my code using `ref`, but it still doesn't work, it says `map.getBounds is not a function`

Comment: @vbernal What version of react-leaflet are you using

Comment: Hii Seth, `"react-leaflet": "2.2.1",` and `"leaflet": "1.4.0",`, if you prefer you can check  in the codesandbox, here's the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-matsumoto-rjffmr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Holy shnikies you're using react-leaflet v2??  Ok I'll adjust my answer